# Dealy in wallpaperManager.setBitmap (bitmap)

Tags: android, bitmapfactory, android-bitmap, android-wallpaper

I am trying to change wallpaper using a widget.
I use the code below to achieve that:
But there is an certain delay every time the code is executed.

Is there any way to **avoid this delay**.

```
...
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance (context);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream (new FileInputStream (file));

//here @file is fetched from a phone storage

wallpaperManager.setBitmap (bitmap);
...
```

Comment: yes, faster CPU+faster memory on device should help, seriously, it alway will take some time ... is this a really long time? on what device? what is a size of the bitmap(in terms of dimentions, not disk size), what takes longer decodeStream or setBitmap?

Comment: not every phone in the market meet this requirement, as i am developing an application i want the code to be fast. Is there any other way achieve this.

Comment: i don't think so ... the only thing that you can do better is decode on different thread (and maybe use setBitmap there too, but i'm not sure if this call doesn't need UI thread)(simple Thread or AsyncTask if it needs back to UI thread) it will not help with the delay but it will help with app's responsiveness  ... are you getting any ANR reports?

Comment: Okay I'll give it a try with different approach.Here are phone's specs:
Sony Xperia Z Ultra
2 GB RAM
Chipset- Qualcomm MSM8274 or MSM8974 Snapdragon 800
CPU- Quad-core 2.2 GHz Krait 400
Gpu- Adreno 330
but the delay is longer then expected, if you have any different approach please let me know.

Comment: grrr, define *longer then expected* and width and height of bitmap ... (1 sec?, 2 sec? more than 3 sec?)

Comment: Delay is somewhere between three and four seconds and bitmap resolution is 900 x 900

Answer (score 1):

I see four options which might help here:

1. Reduce the size of the bitmap before saving it to the file
2. Preload the bitmap (well, if possible)
3. Do all this asyncronous
4. Make sure your heap is as empty as possible before loading the bitmap. If android has to free heap while decoding a large bitmap it will slow down noticeably